# Decrypting file in Java with pre-existing AES key

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am trying to do something pretty simple. I encrypted a file in Windows using AxCrypt. In my Android application, I want to decrypt this file.

The 128bit AES key generated by AxCrypt is

```
CWTr 45Qg eHhy n23d YPC3 DjRi IxUe bt77 TVzQ NtSh HEc=
```

I assume this a Base64 encoded string but maybe I'm wrong. I plugged it in to my code below with the spaces but I also tried without the spaces and I get the same result.

The java code to decrypt the file is below. The decryption process starts but errors out with "last block incomplete in decryption" and the resulting file (an mp4 video) cannot be played.

Java code:

```
       try {
            Utils.logDebug(TAG, "Decrypting!");
            File encfile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/encrypted.axx");
            int read;
            if (!encfile.exists())
                encfile.createNewFile();
            File decfile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/decrypted.mp4");
            if (!decfile.exists())
                decfile.createNewFile();
            FileInputStream encfis = new FileInputStream(encfile);
            FileOutputStream decfos = new FileOutputStream(decfile);
            Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            byte key[] = Base64.decode("CWTr 45Qg eHhy n23d YPC3 DjRi IxUe bt77 TVzQ NtSh HEc=", Base64.DEFAULT);
            SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec(key, 0, key.length, "AES");
            decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(decfos, decipher);
            while ((read = encfis.read()) != -1) {
                cos.write(read);
                cos.flush();
            }
            cos.close();
            Utils.logDebug(TAG, "Done decrypting!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.logError(TAG, "TESTING error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AxCrypt encrypts in CBC mode, as well as compresses, MACs and a number of other details. To decrypt this you'll need to review http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/faq.html and their published source code here.

http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/SourceCode.html

Comment: Does this mean the key it generated is not what I think it is? I didn't use the password feature, I specifically created a key first, and used that. This way there's no hashing of the password etc involved.

Comment: @Flyview It means the format of the file, the encryption mode and other details are completely different from what you are assuming, check the provided docs. And there is, indeed, a great deal of 'etc' involved.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I'm quite new to the whole process of encryption. I'm not set on using AxCrypt by any means. Do you have any suggestions for something I could use to encrypt files in Windows and more easily decrypt them in Java? If that's not possible I suppose I could do the encrypting in Java as well.

Comment: PGP is probably optimal.